# Android - set max width for buttons in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have 2 lines of buttons (in this example showing just one line, just to spare space), that's why I have main LinearLayout and then inner LinearLayout for each button row.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/btnLL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:maxWidth="450dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mainbutton"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn1"
                android:drawablePadding="-18dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="text"
                android:textColor="#eeeeee"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

                        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mainbutton"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn2"
                android:drawablePadding="-18dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="text"
                android:textColor="#eeeeee"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mainbutton"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn3"
                android:drawablePadding="-18dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="text"
                android:textColor="#eeeeee"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is e.g. on tablets, where each button is too wide.

I want to limit the width of each button, but even if I tried to use `android:maxWidth="110dp"` directly for every button, it is ignored, because the buttons have `android:layout_weight="1"`

Also as you can see in my code, I tried to use `android:maxWidth="350dp"` for the inner LinearLayout (also tried to use the same for main LinearLayout), but did not help.

Is there a way to limit the width of buttons in my case, or to limit the width of LinearLayout itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Add the `android:layout_weight` property
2. Set each button's `android:layout_width` to `0dp`.

Now set the required value for `android:maxWidth` for each button, and then modify the weight values to spread the buttons equally in the available space .

Sample Code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btnLL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/mainbutton"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn1"
        android:drawablePadding="-18dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="#eeeeee"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:maxWidth="110dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/mainbutton"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn2"
        android:drawablePadding="-18dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="#eeeeee"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:maxWidth="110dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/mainbutton"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn3"
        android:drawablePadding="-18dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="#eeeeee"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:maxWidth="110dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it doesn't help. When layout weight is set, the max-width is ignored. I can only modify layout weight, but when I set it lower, the buttons will look thin

Answer (score 0):

Seems the only thing that helps is when I set `minWidth` together with `maxWidth` for the inner LinearLayout. And set `layout_width` to `wrap_content`. This is working now.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btnLL"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:minWidth="350dp"
    android:maxWidth="450dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```